# Can I get rid of Android 5.0?

Tags: nexus-7, android-versions, downgrade

I just installed Android 5.0 on my Nexus 7 and now it is 5x slower but it doesn't connect to WiFi. I don`t like this update and I wish I hadn't done it. Now I can't even use my tablet. Is there anything to do?